# Case expression to count multiple groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to group data by its aging. In my sample table, I have 1 column (age) where the numbers range from 1 to 100.. I want to get counts on the number that are <=10, >10, >30 >60 and >90

This is the case expression I used.

```
select age_bracket, count(*) as nbr  
from 
(
select 
case when age > 90 then 'Nbr >90 days'
when age > 60 then 'Nbr >60 days'
when age > 30 then 'Nbr >30 days'
when age > 10 then 'Nbr >10 days'
when age <=10 then 'Nbr <=10 days'
else 'n/a' end as age_bracket    
from [AGE]
)z
group by age_bracket
```

These are the results:

```
Age Bracket     Nbr
Nbr <=10 days   10
Nbr >10 days    20
Nbr >30 days    30
Nbr >60 days    30
Nbr >90 days    10
```

However, this is what I want to see:

```
Age Bracket     Nbr
Nbr <=10 days   10
Nbr >10 days    90
Nbr >30 days    70
Nbr >60 days    40
Nbr >90 days    10
```

Can this be done using a case expression? If so, how would I structure the expression to return the age bracket column and the values in the Nbr column above?

Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Here is a sample of the data. 100 rows (value starts at 1 ends at 100)

```
Age
100
99
98
97
96
95
94
93
```

If you put this in Excel and count how many are

```
>90 you get 10
>60 you get 40 (60 to 100 = 40)
>30 you get 70 (30 to 100 = 70)
>10 you get 90 (10 to 100 = 90)
```

Comment: Sample data would help. It's not clear if you want to aggregate all previous brackets into the next.

Comment: This is what the 'sample' data looks like. It's a table with 1 column, 100 rows and the value in the column starts at 1 and ends at 100.

Age
100
99
98
97
96
95
94
93
92
91
90
89
88
87
86

Comment: Edit your question to include consumables sample data, @tgall0163 .

Comment: The "problem" here is that you are expecting the `CASE` expression to resolve true for *every* condition that would be true, that isn't how they work; a `CASE` expression returns the value from the *first* true condition.

Comment: Ok. If it's not possible using a case statement, is there another way to achieve the output I'm looking for? Was trying to avoid using multiple union queries. That's why I'm asking the experts..

Comment: To avoid multiple UNIONS against table age, one thought is using conditional aggregation and write out 5 columns in a sub-query or cte, then union the output to get your single column. Not saying this is the best option, but is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use where and union results. ie:

```
select 'Nbr <= 10 days' as age_Bracket, count(*) from [Age] where age <= 10
  union
select 'Nbr > 10 days' as age_Bracket, count(*) from [Age] where age > 10
  union
select 'Nbr > 30 days' as age_Bracket, count(*) from [Age] where age > 30
  union
select 'Nbr > 60 days' as age_Bracket, count(*) from [Age] where age > 60
  union
select 'Nbr > 90 days' as age_Bracket, count(*) from [Age] where age > 90;
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `UNION ALL` make more sense? Why force the implicit distinct when it's guaranteed the rows will differ?

Comment: Thanks Cetin. Looks like this will give me what I need. Thom A - I used Union All in the above example as suggested. 

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I didn't say the result would differ, I said the processing would be. You are *forcing* the data engine to *sort* the data and then ensure there are no duplicate values with `UNION`. You *know* there are no duplicates, so why force the data engine to do that?

Comment: Because `UNION` and `UNION ALL` are different. `UNION` **forces** a `DISTINCT` operation on the returned rows, which means that it *must* be sorted first and then all those columns compared. Why bother, it's *impossible* for any duplicate rows.

Comment: *"You are _forcing_ the data engine to _sort_ the data and then ensure there are no duplicate values with `UNION`. You _know_ there are no duplicates, so why force the data engine to do that?"* *"`UNION` **forces** a `DISTINCT` operation on the returned rows, which means that it _must_ be sorted first and then all those columns compared. Why bother, it's _impossible_ for any duplicate rows."* I don't know what else to explain; if you don't understand that, perhaps ask a question about how `UNION` and `UNION ALL` differ (though I suspect I can find a duplicate).

Comment: It's not a "theory" that is how `UNION` behaves.

Comment: I give up... If you prefer to force the `DISTINCT` and sort, then so be it, but it's *not* required.

Comment: That is *not* what I said...

Comment: I'll ask again: Why **force** an implicit `DISTINCT` and sort operation when you **know** that no rows can be the same? I won't provide any further comments until I have an answer to that.

Comment: @ThomA, although UNION is just fine I decided to stop this unnecessary discussion. You are right if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question as you're after `conditional aggregation`, this means your `CASE` will be used within `COUNT`:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN age <= 10 then 1 END) AS "Nbr <=10 days",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN age > 10 then 1 END) AS "Nbr >10 days",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN age > 30 then 1 END) AS "Nbr >30 days",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN age > 60 then 1 END) AS "Nbr >60 days",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN age > 90 then 1 END) AS "Nbr >90 days"
FROM [AGE];
```

Here an example with some sample data: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l3rFo1_t)

If I was wrong and you need the data as separate rows, you could either let your application reform the result of the above query or use `UNION ALL` rather than `CASE` as explained in [Cetin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76733183/18794826).

The linked fiddle shows both queries and their result.